# a1242 keyboard works different than macbook keyboard. WHY?

Tags: macos, keyboard, mac, macbook-pro

I have this keyboard connected as external to my macbook while using external monitor.
[image]

A1242 model.

When I press
<kbd>alt ⌥</kbd> + <kbd>cmd ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>-></kbd> on right side from <kbd>space</kbd> this combination is not working, when on my macbook keyboard it works! Why?

The:

<kbd>alt ⌥</kbd> + <kbd>cmd ⌘</kbd> + <kbd><-</kbd>

or

<kbd>alt ⌥</kbd> + <kbd>cmd ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>-></kbd> on the left side from <kbd>space</kbd>

are wokring OK.